# Check difference in seconds between two times

Tags: c#

Hi all I am currently working on a project where when a certain event happens details about the event including the time that the event occurred is added into a list array.

Once the method has finished I then pass on the list to another method that checks its values. Before I go through the loop I check the current time of my PC and I need to check whether the difference between the time saved in the list array and the current time is greater than 5 seconds.

How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Assuming `dateTime1` and `dateTime2` are [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values:

```
var diffInSeconds = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).TotalSeconds;
```

In your case, you 'd use `DateTime.Now` as one of the values and the time in the list as the other. Be careful of the order, as the result can be negative if `dateTime1` is earlier than `dateTime2`.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, var will end up being double: [TotalSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks... I've just got bitten by using (Milliseconds) by mistake when I should have really used (TotalMilliseconds) ... ouch.

Comment: If I do this with two dates that are 1-2 seconds apart I get 63774476745,095 seconds. What could be wrong?

Comment: var diffInSeconds = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).Seconds; is the good way to do it now.

Comment: @PierreMarsaa that doesn't do what you think it does. Look at the docs for that property, it says the value is always in the range -59 to 59.

Answer (score 31):

DateTime has a [Subtract method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) and an [overloaded `-` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx) for just such an occasion:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeSpan difference = now.Subtract(otherTime); // could also write `now - otherTime`
if (difference.TotalSeconds > 5) { ... }
```

Answer (score 24):

This version always returns the number of seconds difference as a positive number (same result as @freedeveloper's solution):

```
var seconds = System.Math.Abs((date1 - date2).TotalSeconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this to avoid negative interval.

```
var seconds = (date1< date2)? (date2- date1).TotalSeconds: (date1 - date2).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Use `Math.Abs` instead, this code is less readable and performant than just using the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in DateTime.Subtract method can be used as follows

```
double diffInSeconds = dateTime1.Subtract(dateTime2).TotalSecond;
if (diffInSeconds > 5) { /* do stuff */ } ;
```

Answer (score 1):

for .NET Framework

```cs
    int ticks = Environment.TickCount;
    /* Do something */
    ticks = Environment.TickCount - ticks; // difference in milliseconds
    string elapsed = String.Format("Elapsed time: {0} s", (ticks/1000).ToString());
```

for repeated measurement

```cs
    int start_ticks, ticks;
    string elapsed;
    start_ticks = Environment.TickCount;

    /* Do something */
    ticks = Environment.TickCount - start_ticks; // difference in milliseconds
    start_ticks += ticks;
    elapsed = String.Format("Elapsed time: {0} s", (ticks/1000).ToString());

    /* Do something */
    ticks = Environment.TickCount - start_ticks; // difference in milliseconds
    start_ticks += ticks;
    elapsed = String.Format("Elapsed time: {0} s", (ticks/1000).ToString());
```

with .NET Core it's better to use 64-bit `TickCount64`

```cs
    long ticks = Environment.TickCount64;
    ticks = Environment.TickCount64 - ticks;
```