# How to sum group difference between dates using linq/lambda?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I've been searching for a way to make this but I haven't had success. The following is  my problem, I have a table that look like this:

```
ID|CATEGORY|START_DATE               |END_DATE
1  T1       2019-08-29 12:00:00       2019-08-29 12:10:00
2  T1       2019-08-30 13:00:00       2019-08-30 13:20:00
3  T2       2019-08-30 14:00:00       2019-08-30 14:10:00
```

What I want to do is to GROUP BY Category AND SUM the difference between both dates and get a result like this: T1 --> 30 minutes, t2 --> 10 minutes

This is what I've tried:

```
foreach (IGrouping<string, TABLE1> group in result)
{
    series.Add(new PieSerie("SerieName", group.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => (x.START_DATE- x.END_DATE).Value.Seconds  )));
}
```

But it doesn't work. Every single result I get is '0' instead of the total of minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check difference in seconds between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945272/check-difference-in-seconds-between-two-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subtract (as `DateTime`) `2019-08-30 14:00:00` from `2019-08-30 14:10:00`, you get (as a `TimeSpan`) `00:10:00`, which is to say "zero hours, 10 minutes, and zero seconds". The "and zero seconds" is a clue why you're getting `0` from `.Seconds`. You probably want `.TotalSeconds` (which will be `600`), or just keep the entire `TimeSpan` itself.

Comment: I was conffused, I'm new at lambda and linq queries, and I was always worked with DateTime, never with TimeSpan. that's why I was trying to get seconds like that. But TotalSeconds Solved the problem. Thanks !!